# Android SearchView OnFocusChangeListener: onFocusChange is not called at all

Tags: android, android-fragments, focus, listener, searchview

I have a `SearchView` in an Activity; when the user executes search, a `Fragment` containing the search results is adding to the same Activity.

Now what I want is that when the `SearchView` is clicked (so it gets the focus, and the user types there), *the `Fragment` already displayed (containig the search results) should become dim/blurred.*

So I tried to set an `OnFocusChangedListener` for the `SearchView` in the `onActivityCreated` life cycle callback method of the `Fragment`, **but it does not seem to be called at all.**

```
final Activity myActivity = getActivity();
        Log.i(TAG, "myActivity>"+myActivity.toString());//check
        SearchView mySearchView = (SearchView) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.searchActivity_searchView);
        Log.i(TAG, "mySearchView>"+mySearchView.toString());//check
        mySearchView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onFocusChange OF OnFocusChangeListener IN SearchResultsFragment CALLED.");
                if (hasFocus) {
                    myActivity.getWindow().setDimAmount(1.0f);
                }
            }
        });
```

So am I missing something? **What should I do to get the `onFocusChanged` called when the user clicks and thus activites the `SearchView` to type their Search query in it?**

**Note:** If an entire SSCCE's code is required, please ask in comments, I'll post it.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try with setOnClickListener()?

Comment: @MohanRaj Just tried that, even that is not being called =(

Comment: You can directly try this out in the activity which holds your search view,Instead of getting reference inside fragment ?

Comment: @MohanRaj There isn't a problem with the reference. I have a check which prints the `toString` on the `SearchView` got by `findViewById()` =(

Answer (score 81):

Sorry for late answer, but I had the same problem and found this question during search, so it might perhaps help other people.

Have you tried using `mySearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener()` instead of `mySearchView.setOnFocusChangeListener()`?

Worked for me.

Comment: I'll have to try it. I'll get back to you after that.

Comment: Works well- thanks.. This should be considered as correct answer